How does the camera app find/use/integrate the various multiple cameras on each phone?
My current phone is a Unihertz Tank 3 Pro running Android 14. It has 4 cameras.

How does the camera app find/use/integrate the various multiple cameras on the phone?
Also, is the app for a phone specially customized to do that - or if I use an alternative, like LMC8.4 (it doesn't have a special version for my particular phone), will it also see and use the wide-angle and telephoto cameras?
Finally, can I influence how the app uses the various cameras?


Hi, I cleaned up the question because meta-commentary distracts from the real question. Your question on Photography.SE was migrated here, resulting in a duplicate of this question, and the original question locked. I believe the reason why it's migrated is because it's not really about photography, but more about how Android works.

Summarizing the questions:
Can I influence how the app uses the various cameras?
Android camera apps would need to expose any feature to the end user.
How does the multi-lens thing work on Android?
Android app developers have documentation regarding the usage of multiple physical cameras and logical cameras: Multi-camera API: The difference between logical and physical cameras
But in the end it would be up to the device exposing the feature for any Android developer to use and then up to the app developer to expose/integrate as appropriate in their camera app.
Do device manufacturers use 'hidden' or 'specialized' APIs not available to third-party camera app developers?
Yes, the documentation I linked to explicitly called it out.

Many phone manufacturers develop first-party camera applications, which usually come pre-installed on their devices. To use all of the hardware's capabilities, they may use private or hidden APIs or receive special treatment from the driver implementation that other applications do not have access to.`

For example Samsung is known for this: Recording video at 120FPS using a third-party app seems not possible on Samsung S series and I would not be surprised if other device manufacturers used APIs not available to third-party developers possibly as the manufacturer is able to calibrate their software to match their hardware. However just because a manufacturer can doesn't mean that they do (probably on low-end budget devices).
Does Android have a way to expose specialized camera features to apps?
The Android team has provided an API call Camera Extensions and even provides a non-comprehensive list of devices with support.
Again specific feature support varies from device to device and incumbent on the camera app developer to use such feature. Additions to the existing list of features, like bokeh and HDR, are at the discretion of the Android team and have no schedule or predictions.
If I want to ask for software that does X feature should I ask here?
No. Stack Exchange has a Software Recommendations site which would be more appropriate for questions like Free real HDR camera app for Android. As the Open Camera app mention in the answer there is open source, that app does provide a good baseline as to what is possible for third-party developers.

"it would be up to the device exposing the feature for any Android developer to use and then up to the app developer to expose/integrate as appropriate in their camera app."
I would imagine this is the key - do they do that often, and do they do it in a standard way, so that apps are likely to know where to look and what to find?

@WombatPete Updated answer to include Camera Extensions but again its up to the app author to integrate.

It's interesting. I wonder - is there a way I can test when the camera app is using cameras other than the basic front and back cameras? If so, I could answer the question for the specific case that I'm dealing with!
Of course, It probably gets complex if the app combines the output of more than one camera...

@WombatPete Developer documentation has an example: https://developer.android.com/media/camera/camera2/multi-camera#zoom For a specific device I would look at prior mentioned Open Camera and see if that app exposes what you need. While you can create a new question with details about what you are trying do with Open Camera and your hardware, a quick search shows possible camera issues with that make/model.
